# Route annotations

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

For some reason I can't get the routes to work with annotations. Here is the code I tried.

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * Class PostsController
 */

    class PostsController
    {
     /**
      * @Route('forum/posts', 'bd_forum_posts')
      */
     public function indexAction()
     {
       return new Response('Hello from PostsController');
     }
    }
```

When I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/posts` 
I get route not found
The path forum/posts is not displayed on console router:debug output too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set app/config/routing.yml correctly? It should be like this:

```
vendor_bundle:
  resource: "@VendorXYBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /
```

Then, the format for routing should be this:

```
/**
 * @Route('/forum/posts', name='bd_forum_posts')
 */
```

Note the starting slash in the route and the name property.

...and don't forget to namespace your controller correctly. It should be under Vendor\XYBundle\Controller.